# Sass function to construct a URL

Tags: sass

I'm trying to write an SCSS function that returns a URL. (So I could use it like `background-image: getURL(thing);`)

The difficult thing is I want to interpolate arguments into it, including escaping the args, e.g. `#` should become `%23` so it is URL-safe.

Is this sort of thing even possible with Sass?

```
@function getURL($name, $color: #ffffff) {
  // ???
}

// How I want it to work:
getURL('foo');
  // returns: url("http://example.com/foo.png?color=%23ffffff")

// And if possible, this would be cool
// (accepting any color type, and turning it into a hex color):
getURL('bar', rgb(255,0,0));
  // returns: url("http://example.com/bar.png?color=%23ff0000")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [write your own Ruby method](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adding_custom_functions) to do the URL encoding and color conversion. It looks like [Color#inspect](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Value/Color.html#inspect-instance_method) returns a hex representation for colors with no alpha value.

You may be able to do some very simple URL encoding with SASS's [`str-` index/insert/slice functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#string_functions).

It might be easier to fake it:

```
@function getURL($name, $color-hex-str: ffffff) {
    @return url(http://example.com/#{$name}.png?color=%23#{$color-hex-str});
}
```